# Foreman not working with a rake tast on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, foreman

So I have my rails backend running at port 3001 and may React frontend running at port 3000.

I want to setup a simple `rake start` task to start both.

To do so, I use the `foreman` gem, which works perfectly when I run: `foreman start -f Procfile.dev`.

However: when I run my task: `rake start`, I get the following error:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 36257
15:56:57 web.1  | started with pid 36258
15:56:57 api.1  | started with pid 36259
15:56:57 api.1  | /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/foreman-0.64.0/bin/foreman-runner: line 41: exec: PORT=3001: not found
15:56:57 api.1  | exited with code 127
15:56:57 system | sending SIGTERM to all processes
15:56:57 web.1  | terminated by SIGTERM
```

Here is my my `start.rake` file:

```
namespace :start do
  desc 'Start dev server'
  task :development do
    exec 'foreman start -f Procfile.dev'
  end

  desc 'Start production server'
  task :production do
    exec 'NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true npm run postinstall && foreman start'
  end
end
task :start => 'start:development'
```

and my `Procfile.dev` file:

```
web: cd client && PORT=3000 npm start
api: PORT=3001 && bundle exec rails s
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same issue. I am not sure why, but when foreman is running from rake, it is unable to handle multiple commands on the same line, e.g.

```
web: cd client && PORT=3000 npm start
```

To solve the issue, I changed my Procfile.dev to

```
web: npm start --prefix client
api: bundle exec rails s -p 3001
```

and in my package.json, I changed

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    ...
}
```

to

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "PORT=3000 react-scripts start",
    ...
}
```

This allows you to specify the ports for both react and rails servers, and works fine with both

`foreman start -f Procfile.dev` and `rake start`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know Foreman, but every morning I start my dev environment with [teamocil](https://github.com/remiprev/teamocil). Here is an [example](https://github.com/aarkerio/dotfiles/blob/master/teamocil/schnell.yml) file.

Add an alias to your .bash_alias file:

```
 alias s2="cd /home/manuel/chipotle/schnell && tmux new-session -d 'teamocil schnell' \; attach"
```

so you just need to type "s2" in the console and all, including the database prompt, is up and ready.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little bit late, but essentially you shouldn't use multi-line command, always try avoiding then. you could change your syntax and make it online with some flags as fallow:

```
web: npm start --port 3000 --prefix client 
api: bundle exec rails s -p 3001
```

I hope it could help anyone facing the same issue.
Happy Coding